# MVC implementation of many to many relationships

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, many-to-many, master-detail

This is done using MVC .net framework and entity framework "database first" approach. There is a many to many relationship between two tables. They are connected through third table that has combined key as id from first table and id from second table.

```
  public class ManyToManyTable
  {
    [Required]
    [Key, Column(Order=0)]
    public int firsttableid { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Key, Column(Order=1)]
    public int secondtableid { get; set; }

    public int something { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("firsttableid")]
    public virtual FirstTable firstTable { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("secondtableid")]
    public virtual SecondTable secondTable { get; set; }
}
```

First and Second table have some id which is primary key.

I want to create View and Controller method that enables master detail entry form for this ManyToManyTable. that would have FirstTable in Master and SecondTAble in details, and all to be saved in ManyToManyTable when button Save is pressed.

Of course, both First and Second Table have this property:

```
public virtual ICollection<ManyToManyTable> ManyToManyTables { get; set; }
```

What is the easiest way to implement cases like this one?
Thank you!

Comment: once you start adding columns unrelated to a strict many to many i.e. "public int something {get;set;}."  you are creating a new entity and it should be mapped as a 1 to many - many to 1 relationship.

Answer (score 0):

EF has a default conventions for many-to-many relationships. No need to create specific
mapping class. You have to include navigation properties in both "FirstTable" and "SecondTable" Class as shown below.

```
 public class FirstTable
{
    public FirstTable()
    {
        secondTableProperties = new HashSet<SecondTable>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MyProperty2 { get; set; }
    public int MyProperty3 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SecondTable> secondTableProperties  { get; set; }
}

public class SecondTable
{
public SecondTable()
{
        FirstTableProperties = new HashSet<FirstTable>();
}
public int Id { get; set; }
public int MyProperty2 { get; set; }
public int MyProperty3 { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<FirstTable> FirstTableProperties { get; set; }
}
```

Remove mapping class from  DBContext , only include above two classes. Build and  run the application , EF will automatically create a Mapping table in SQL server. Usually the Mapping table contains only the primary keys of other two tables.

You can use Fluent API to take some control on the created  mapping table

```
modelBuilder.Entity<FirstTable>()
            .HasMany<SecondTable>(s => s.FirstTableProperties)
            .WithMany(c => c.secondTableProperties)
            .Map(cs =>
                    {
                        cs.MapLeftKey("FirstTableId");
                        cs.MapRightKey("SecondTableId");
                        cs.ToTable("ManyToManyTable");
                    });
```

If you want to work with a join table with additional properties, above mentioned   many-to-many relationship won't work . In that case  you will have to create  two one-to-many relationships as shown below.

```
public class FirstTable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MyProperty2 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ManyToManyTable> manytomany { get; set; }
}

public class SecondTable
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public int MyProperty2 { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<ManyToManyTable> manytomany { get; set; }
}

public ManyToManyTable
{
[Required]
[Key, Column(Order=0)]
public int firsttableid { get; set; }
[Required]
[Key, Column(Order=1)]
public int secondtableid { get; set; }
public int AdditionalProperty { get; set; }
public virtual FirstTable first { get; set; }
public virtual SecondTable Second { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I wasn't clear, tables are implemented like that. I just don't know how to create view and Action for, for instance, Create, or update, in form of Master Detail where First Table is Master and second is in details.

Comment: I hope you have separate data models for your MVC side and data layer side . Above code just shows the entities in data layer. In MVC side you can  create a separate view model that has all the required properties to capture details from the user. When save button is clicked you have to validate the view model and mapp it to appropriate  entity model and save into database                               
 context.FirstTable.Add(new FirstTable { prop1= model.M1 , prop2 = model.M2}); 
 context.SecondTable.Add(new SecondTable{ prop1= model.D1 , prop2 = model.D2} );
context.SaveChanges()

Comment: Thank you for advice. No, I did not separate them, it seems that it's something that was not really well planned in EF MVC combo. I used to work in Oracle where master detail can be made in literally few seconds.So, it confuses me how hard is to implement the same thing in .net mvc. It requires so many helpers...